# Simplify my code

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

```
    If bar1.Visible = False Or bar1.Value > 0 Then
        npc1.Visible = False
    End If
    If bar2.Visible = False Or bar2.Value >= 0 Then
        npc2.Visible = False
    End If
    If bar3.Visible = False Or bar3.Value >= 0 Then
        npc3.Visible = False
    End If
    If bar4.Visible = False Or bar4.Value >= 0 Then
        npc4.Visible = False
    End If
    If bar5.Visible = False Or bar5.Value >= 0 Then
        npc5.Visible = False
    End If
```

This goes on up to bar10 and npc10
I don't know how to apply loops or arrays.  I am not the best a programming but my project is due soon and i'm freaking out because it has to look good.  Please help and break it down if you can!

Comment: This is not a place to make others to do your project work..

Comment: Ok, what is bar and npc? Is this a user form or are these cells or...? We need a bit more info to be able to help.

Comment: The folks over at [codereview.se] are pretty good at making working code look good and work better. If you included more context, like, the whole procedure perhaps, this could be a good Code Review question.

Answer (score 1):

```
For n = 1 to 10
    Set c = Me.Controls("bar" & n)
    If c.Visible = False Or c.Value > 0 Then
        Me.Controls("npc" & n).Visible = False
    End If
Next n
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 10 Step 1
    If bar(i).Visible = False Or bar(i).Value >= 0 Then
        npc(i).Visible = False
    End If
Next i
```